# Firing Blur event from AngularJS Custom Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a custom angularjs directive and need to perform a specific validation only after blur on an input element. But the problem is the validation is happening even after onkeypress event. 
Although, for the first time its happening correctly on blur and from 2nd time onwards its happening even with onkeypress.

Entire working sample is in below fiddle. Please check for yourself and feel free to edit and try as well. I am not sure what is going wrong. I need the customValidator() function to be performing only after blur is done.

```
angular.module('app').directive('strongSecret', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        element.bind('blur', function customValidator() {
        scope.$apply(attr.strongSecret);
        scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(value) {}
```

[fiddle Entire Working Sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/ggcoder81/2n5wx06j/4/)

Appreciate any help!

Comment: It updates on every keystroke because of the watcher.  Whenever the value changes, the watcher fires and runs the function.

Comment: Ok so how to do without watcher? I need the element value for validation and thats why I used watcher to get the elements value and I am not having any idea for an alternate way. Please suggest.

Comment: Personally, I would remove the directive and use `ng-blur` to point to a function on the controller that validates the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it happens after an onkeypress event is because the function is set as a $parser in the model controller.
Angular documentation on parsers :

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control reads value from the DOM. The functions are called in array order, each passing its return value through to the next. The last return value is forwarded to the $validators collection. Parsers are used to sanitize / convert the $viewValue

I assume this is why your function is being called every key press, the parser fires every key press.

You are binding it to onBlur as well, I can't quite figure out why it does it only the first time on blur.

The correct way to do this would be to split it into three functions that return true or false (one for each validation rule) and assign as $validators instead of  $parsers. You don't even need to assign you function to the on blur event as well, you just need to use the ng-model-options to pass the updateOn blur option (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms look in custom model triggers). This will make your validator fire only on blur and not every key press.